# CAS Server gradle not able to resolve depencency

Tags: java, gradle, cas, jasig

I was trying to build CAS version 5.3.x and I am facing below issue running Gradle build.

```
> Task :support:cas-server-support-duo-core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':support:cas-server-support-duo-core:compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve net.unicon.iam:duo-client:0.2.2.
  Required by:
      project :support:cas-server-support-duo-core
   > Could not resolve net.unicon.iam:duo-client:0.2.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/unicon/iam/duo-client/0.2.2/duo-client-0.2.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/unicon/iam/duo-client/0.2.2/duo-client-0.2.2.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve net.unicon.iam:duo-client:0.2.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/uniconiam/maven/net/unicon/iam/duo-client/0.2.2/duo-client-0.2.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/uniconiam/maven/net/unicon/iam/duo-client/0.2.2/duo-client-0.2.2.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve net.unicon.iam:duo-client:0.2.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/unicon/iam/duo-client/0.2.2/duo-client-0.2.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/unicon/iam/duo-client/0.2.2/duo-client-0.2.2.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a missing library dependency. Try to add 
`compile group: 'net.unicon.iam', name: 'duo-client', version: '0.2.2'` to your gradle and build again.